# Emacs won't list any packages and won't let me install any packages

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, melpa

I have been setting up my emacs on a mac. I haven't been able to install any packages or even list available packages since I have set up my emacs installation on this computer. Every time I try to refresh the contents of the package repositories I get the following error and backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp <!DOCTYPE)
  package--read-archive-file("archives/marmalade/archive-contents")
  package-read-archive-contents("marmalade")
  package-read-all-archive-contents()
  package--update-downloads-in-progress(("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
  package--download-one-archive(("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
  package--download-and-read-archives(nil)
  package-refresh-contents()
  funcall-interactively(package-refresh-contents)
  #<subr call-interactively>(package-refresh-contents record nil)
  ad-Advice-call-interactively(#<subr call-interactively> package-refresh-contents record nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-call-interactively #<subr call-interactively> (package-refresh-contents record nil))
  call-interactively(package-refresh-contents record nil)
  command-execute(package-refresh-contents record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "package-refresh-contents")
  smex-read-and-run(("pwd" "ido-wide-find-file-or-pop-dir" "bookmark-delete" "bookmark-jump" "bookmark-set" "replace-string" "flower-client-connect" "tramp-cleanup-connection" "rgrep" "tramp-cleanup-all-buffers" "tramp-cleanup-all-connections" "package-install" "magit-status" "flycheck-mode" "flycheck-set-checker-executable" "grep" "goto-line" "yank" "js2-mode" "grep-find" "rename-file" "magit-commit" "revert-buffer" "shrink-window" "clipboard-yank" "make-directory" "tramp-cleanup-this-connection" "5x5" "slime" "version" "php-mode" "web-mode" "irony-mode" "company-mode" "magit-rebase" "enlarge-window" "undo-tree-mode" "whitespace-mode" "package-initialize" "package-refresh-contents" "term" "imenu" "shell" "doctor" "eshell" "blackbox" "sgml-mode" "tern-mode" "tramp-bug" "calculator" ...))
  smex()
  funcall-interactively(smex)
  #<subr call-interactively>(smex nil nil)
  ad-Advice-call-interactively(#<subr call-interactively> smex nil nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-call-interactively #<subr call-interactively> (smex nil nil))
  call-interactively(smex nil nil)
  command-execute(smex)
```

Below is my code that I use to initialize the package repos.

```
;; Package Managers
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.com/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Has anyone else had an issue like this? How do I get a clean response from the package repositories so I can install packages?

EDIT:

I am using GNU Emacs version 25.1.1

Comment: Marmalade is not a thing anymore? That could be part of the problem. Emcas could be failing to get all of the packages lists because marmalade fails. Whenever I do package-refresh-contents and then I try to list packages, it has 0 items.

Comment: Marmalade is on https as well. I will try a few things and then update.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi It appears that you are correct. It loads all of the packages with no trouble now. Do you want to submit that as an answer so you can get those karma points? It will help maintain your top 2% overall :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that their is no http://marmalade-repo.com/packages/. The correct url is https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/.

Credit goes to @jenesaisquoi. This user found the answer in the comments on my original post.

```
;; Package Managers
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
```